# Restoring a Windows VM automatically in AWS

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, snapshot, aws-cli, restore

We have a Windows 2012 R2 VM called **test01** in AWS and it's used for automatic tests. There is another server which connects to the test VM for running some tests. Sometimes the tests mess up the VM.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to restore the VM in AWS.

My plan is:

1. Make a snapshot of a working test01 VM.
2. When test01 gets messed up, script is run and it does the following:

   1. Shutdown test01.
   2. Block access to test01, so that no tests can be run.
   3. Detach messed up volume.
   4. Create volume from the working snapshot and attach it.
   5. Power up test01 and let Windows run updates.
   6. Create snapshot after Windows updates have been run.
   7. Allow access to test01.
3. Cleanup other snapshots except the original working VM and the latest updated snapshot.

There are some Linux VMs running on our AWS account also, so I could write a Bash script with AWS CLI and run it from a Linux VM.

Would anybody think some other better approach?